# sorting unique values in a php array

Tags: php, mysql

I originally posted this [Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876319/php-while-loop-or-if-statement-in-another-while-loop) and have expanded my question and moved onto this question from it.

I'm trying to split up an array and remove some partial unique values from a `MYSQL SELECT QUERY` with `PHP`.

Here's the out put I'm getting...

```
Array ( [Order_ID] => 1 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [OrderDate] => [lotCode] => 401042 [qty] => 8 [0] => 
Array ( [0] => 1 [Order_ID] => 1 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => 993647 [lotCode] => 993647 [4] => 9 [qty] => 9 ) [1] => 
Array ( [0] => 1 [Order_ID] => 1 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => 401040 [lotCode] => 401040 [4] => 55 [qty] => 55 ) [2] => 
Array ( [0] => 1 [Order_ID] => 1 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => 401040 [lotCode] => 401040 [4] => 66 [qty] => 66 ) [3] => 
Array ( [0] => 1 [Order_ID] => 1 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => 401042 [lotCode] => 401042 [4] => 8 [qty] => 8 ) ) 

Array ( [Order_ID] => 7 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [OrderDate] => [0] => 
Array ( [0] => 2 [Order_ID] => 2 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => [lotCode] => [4] => [qty] => ) [1] => 
Array ( [0] => 3 [Order_ID] => 3 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => [lotCode] => [4] => [qty] => ) [2] => 
Array ( [0] => 4 [Order_ID] => 4 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => [lotCode] => [4] => [qty] => ) [3] => 
Array ( [0] => 5 [Order_ID] => 5 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => [lotCode] => [4] => [qty] => ) [4] => 
Array ( [0] => 6 [Order_ID] => 6 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => [lotCode] => [4] => [qty] => ) [5] => 
Array ( [0] => 7 [Order_ID] => 7 [1] => 42534 [Customer_ID] => 42534 [2] => [OrderDate] => [3] => [lotCode] => [4] => [qty] => ) )
```

From this Query...

```
<?php

$withLotCodes = array();
$noLotCodes = array();

$OrdersToShip2 = mysql_query("
        SELECT o.Order_ID, o.Customer_ID, o.OrderDate, olc.lotCode, olc.qty
        FROM Orders o
        LEFT JOIN OrdersLotCodes olc ON o.Order_ID = olc.Order_ID
        WHERE o.LotCoded = 0 ORDER BY o.Order_ID");

if($OrdersToShip2) {

    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($OrdersToShip2))
    {
            if(!isset($info['lotCode'])){
                // if NO lotCode
                $noLotCodes['Order_ID']     = $info['Order_ID'];
                $noLotCodes['Customer_ID']  = $info['Customer_ID'];
                $noLotCodes['OrderDate']    = $info['OrderDate'];

                array_push($noLotCodes,$info);

                }else{
                // if YES lotCode
                $withLotCodes['Order_ID']    = $info['Order_ID'];
                $withLotCodes['Customer_ID'] = $info['Customer_ID'];
                $withLotCodes['OrderDate']   = $info['OrderDate'];
                $withLotCodes['lotCode']     = $info['lotCode'];
                $withLotCodes['qty']         = $info['qty'];

                array_push($withLotCodes,$info);

                }
    }
            }else{
            echo "encountered an error.".mysql_error();
    } 

print_r($withLotCodes); 
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($noLotCodes);   

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

As you see, it breaks the `array` up into orders that have `'lotCodes'` and orders that do not so I now have two `arrays`.

Now, I'm trying to remove the duplicate values for the `'Order_ID'` `'Customer_ID` & `'OrderDate'` that have the `'lotCode'` values in the first `array`. I only want them to appear once followed by the lotCode values as many as they may be.

I tried using `array_unique` but that removed the rest with the `lotCodes` that I need for the output.

So, what I'm going for would be something like:

```
Order_ID, Customer_ID, OrderDate, lotCode, qty, lotCode, qty, lotCode, qty, lotCode, qty
```

Instead of:

```
Order_ID, Customer_ID, OrderDate, lotCode, qty
Order_ID, Customer_ID, OrderDate, lotCode, qty
Order_ID, Customer_ID, OrderDate, lotCode, qty
Order_ID, Customer_ID, OrderDate, lotCode, qty
```

I hope that's clear.

Any suggestions on this guys?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your actual code, you could do something like this

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($OrdersToShip2))
{
    if(!isset($info['lotCode'])){
        if( !isset( $noLotCodes[$info['Order_ID']]) ) {
            $noLotCodes[$info['Order_ID']] = $info;
        }
        $noLotCodes[$info['Order_ID']]['lotCode'][$info['lotCode']] = $info['qty'];

    }else{
        if( !isset( $withLotCodes[$info['Order_ID']]) ) {
            $withLotCodes[$info['Order_ID']] = $info;
        }
        $withLotCodes[$info['Order_ID']]['lotCode'][$info['lotCode']] = $info['qty'];

    }
}
```

What this will give you is a multi-dimensional array with the order "header" info (order_id, customer_id and order_date etc) at the top level and then a sub-array of lotCodes and qty.

But as a more general point you should move away from using the mysql_ family of functions - they're deprecated. You should use mysqli_ or even better PDO.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the values for each `lotCode` & `qty` that are a part of the `Order_ID` without getting the `Order_ID` more than once. I just can't figure out the proper statement for it.

Comment: @Monty Ok, I've tweaked my code to provide that and added a little bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not makes things easier (from my point of view) by creating an array like

```
// you create your order array
$orders = array();
// Then for each lot and quantity
$order[$Order_ID][$Customer_ID][$OrderDate][] = array( 'lotCode'=>$lotcode, 'qty'=>$qty );
$order[$Order_ID][$Customer_ID][$OrderDate][] = array( 'lotCode'=>$lotcode2, 'qty'=>$qty2 );

// You can test if a specified value exist with isset
// Like
if ( isset (  $order[1][42534 ][3] ) )
{
   // Found order list with order ID 1, cutomer id 42534 and order date 3
}
```

Edit:

```
// Select emulation
$mysqlreturnarrayemul = array();
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[0]['Order_ID'] = 1;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[0]['Customer_ID'] = 42534;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[0]['OrderDate'] = 3;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[0]['lotCode'] = 1;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[0]['qty'] = 200;

$mysqlreturnarrayemul[1]['Order_ID'] = 1;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[1]['Customer_ID'] = 42534;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[1]['OrderDate'] = 3;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[1]['lotCode'] = 5;
$mysqlreturnarrayemul[1]['qty'] = 8456;

// you create your order array
$orders = array();
foreach ( $mysqlreturnarrayemul as $info )
{
    // Then you add lot code and quantity
    $order[$info['Order_ID']][$info['Customer_ID']][$info['OrderDate']][] = $info['lotCode'];
    $order[$info['Order_ID']][$info['Customer_ID']][$info['OrderDate']][] = $info['qty'];
}

// You can test if a specified value exist with isset
// Like
if ( isset (  $order[1][42534 ][3] ) )
{
   // Found order list with order ID 1, cutomer id 42534 and order date 3
   print_r($order[1][42534 ][3]);

}
// print_r: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 200 [2] => 5 [3] => 8456 )
```

Regards

Comment: I updated my post to show you a simple way to append the value in your array. You just have to get the Order_iD once (along with custimer id or orer date)